# unique words from a file c++

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream

ts been 3 days i just cant identify whats wrong with the program the program should compare words by words instead it only comparing a character to charcter its is showing like if i have words like (aaa bbb cc dd ) the result its printing is a b and same is the sentence file if i put paragraphs to compare its only comparing few character please help me

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()    
{
    ifstream myfile("unique.text");

    int count = 0;

    string temp;

    string a;    

    int i,j;

    while(getline(myfile,temp))
    {
        for(i=0 ; i < sizeof(temp); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (temp[i] == temp[j])
                    break;
            }   

            if (i == j)
                cout << temp [i] <<" , ";
        }

        myfile.close (); 
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please click on "edit" and fix your code, there are a lot of space characters that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems

`temp` is of type `string`. `sizeof` is not the way to determine the length of a `string` (it's used for determining things like the number of bytes in an `int`). You want:

`temp.length()`

Secondly, indexing into a string (`temp[n]`) gives you the nth character, not the nth word.

You can make `getline` split into words by adding a third delimiter parameter:

```
getline (myfile, temp, ' '))
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response sir i have done what you asked but now its printing every word that i am putting in a file

Comment: It's not simply a case of changing that one line. That's how to read in individual words. How you process them is for you to work out.

Comment: @Mightybendar And if you really want to thank people, the correct thing to do is at least upvoting their answers ! And accepting the one that you feel is the best answer. That's how it works here.

Answer (score 0):

So, some bugs in your code.

Mixing up characters and strings, closing the file in the while loop and not storing last words.

One recommenadtion. Before you write code, write comments for what you want to do.

Meaning, make a design, before you start coding. That is very important.

For your problem at hand in the title of this thread:

> unique words from a file c++

I prepared 3 different solutions. The first is just using very simple constructs. The second is using a `std::vector`. And, the 3rd is the C++ solution using the C++ algorithm library.

Please see:

Simple, but lengthy

And not recommended, because we should not use raw pointers for owned memory and should not use `new`

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const std::string fileName{ "unique.text" };


unsigned int numberOfWords() {

    // Here we will count the number of words in the file
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    // Open the file. File must not be already open
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream(fileName);

    // Check, if we could open the file
    if (sourceFileStream) {

        // Simply read all words and increment the counter
        std::string temp;
        while (sourceFileStream >> temp) ++counter;
    }
    else {
        // In case of problem
        std::cerr << "\nCould not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {

    // Get the number of words in the source file
    unsigned size = numberOfWords();

    // Allocate a dynamic array of strings. Size is the count of the words in the file
    // Including doubles. So we will waste a little bit of space
    std::string* words = new std::string[size+1];

    // Open the source file
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream(fileName);

    // Check, if it could be opened
    if (sourceFileStream) {

        // We will read first into a temporary variable
        std::string temp;
        // Her we will count number of the unique words
        unsigned int wordCounter = 0;

        // Read all words in the file
        while (sourceFileStream >> temp) {

            // We will search, if we have read alread the word before. We assume NO for the beginning
            bool wordIsAlreadyPresent = false;

            // Go through all alread read words, and check, if the just read word is already existing
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < wordCounter; ++i) {

                // Check, if just read word is already in the word array
                if (temp == words[i]) {

                    // Yes it is, set flag, and stop the loop.
                    wordIsAlreadyPresent = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if the word was not already there
            if (! wordIsAlreadyPresent) {
                // Then add the just read temporary word into our array
                words[wordCounter] = temp;

                // And increment the counter
                ++wordCounter;
            }
        }

        // Show all read unique words
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < wordCounter; ++i) {
            std::cout << words[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
    else { // In case of error
        std::cerr << "\nCould not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
    delete[] words;
}
```

---

2. Using a vector. Already more compact and better readable

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const std::string fileName{ "unique.text" };

int main() {

    // Open the source file
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream(fileName);

    // Check, if the source file is oepen
    if (sourceFileStream) {

        // Temporary string for holding just read words
        std::string temp;

        // In this vector we will store all unique words
        std::vector<std::string> words;

        // Read all words from the source file
        while (sourceFileStream >> temp) {

            // We will search, if we have read alread the word before. We assume NO for the beginning
            bool wordIsAlreadyPresent = false;

            // Go through all alread read words, and check, if the just read word is already existing
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
                // Check, if just read word is already in the word vector
                if (temp == words[i]) {

                    // Yes it is, set flag, and stop the loop.
                    wordIsAlreadyPresent = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if the word was not already there
            if (not wordIsAlreadyPresent) {

                // Then add the just read temporary word into our array
                words.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << words[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nCould not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
}
```

---

And 3., more advance C++ programming. Just very few lines and elegant code.

But too difficult to understand for starters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string fileName{ "unique.text" };

int main() {

    // Open the source file and check, if it could be opend and there is no failure
    if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream(fileName); sourceFileStream) {

        // Read all words (everything delimited by a white space) into a set
        std::set words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(sourceFileStream), {});

        // Now we have a set with all unique words. Show this on the screen
        std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
    // If  we could not open the source file
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nCould not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```